# Get Google Form ID for edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I am using Google Form. I submit the form. How can I get a/the link for editing the answer of this form, by using Google Apps script?

I want to send an email containing a link for editing answers to multiple emails, instead of just 1 email (as google form provides).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the link to edit the "answers" already submitted,

```
function onFormSubmit(e){ //Trigger for this function installed from form(not spreadsheet)
    MailApp.sendEmail("recipient@example.com,recipient2@example.com",
        "Your form has a new response. Form response edit link below:",
         e.response.getEditResponseUrl());
}
```

#### References:

- [Form Submit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_4)
- [ResponseUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getEditResponseUrl())
- [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body)
- [Trigger Installation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)