# Editing a google doc form submission?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I submitted a response to a google form I was sent. I had the option to edit it afterwards however I didn't save the URL.

Is there anyway to find the URL or to edit my submission?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Google Form ID for edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52408878/get-google-form-id-for-edit)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the edit response URL on submission.* (And have it written to a sheet, or emailed.)

In your case however, if you want to edit your previous response you can go to the form using the same url. (If it is limited to one response, you should have an option to edit your response.)

- Using Google App Script